# How to drop keys from internal sks keyserver

Tags: pgp

How do I drop keys from an internal SKS keyserver.

SKS fingerprints are in SHA1, but sks drop command is looking for an md5, how do I properly get the MD5 fingerprint from a key on an sks keyserver.

This command gives the SHA1 Fingerprint

```
gpg --fingerprint username
```

```
sks drop $(sha1_fingerprint)
hash should be exactly 32 characters long
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

md5sum not working any more, because of now [keyHash](https://github.com/SKS-Keyserver/sks-keyserver/blob/master/keyHash.ml) is MD5 hash of sorted key, for me has worked:

- get hash in browser, by adding &hash=on to sks url
- sks drop ${hash_from_web}

Answer (score 1):

that should be :

1. Export pub key to a file
2. md5sum <key_file>